# Domain based email senders in app engine in a django application

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-workspace, googledns

I have a google app engine django application, I want to send emails through a custom domain mail. When I try to add the domain mail user@domain.com to mail senders in app engine, I get the error :
***The following emails could not be added because they are on a different domain. The email must be associated with a Google Apps domain or Google group. If the email is associated with a Google group, your role in the group must be Owner or Manager:***

The site is hosted on google domains and registered on Google Workspace. I have added the google SPF Record and the email is the owner of the domain yet still produces the error. I have added the DNS Records to the Google Domain Records, yet it cannot allow the email to be added to the email senders on app engine. Is there a way I can make it work other than using other party mail senders like sendgrid

Answer (score 2):

1. According to the documentation of [Who can send email](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail#who_can_send_mail),

> For security purposes, the sender address of a message must be one of the following:
>
> i) The Gmail or Google Workspace Account of the user who is currently signed in
>
> ii) Any email address of the form anything@[MY_PROJECT_ID].appspotmail.com or anything@[MY_PROJECT_NUMBER].appspotmail.com
>
> iii) Any email address listed in the Cloud Console under Email API Authorized Senders

This is telling you that GAE is expecting one of the following

i) the gmail of the account that owns the App Engine Project (i.e. the user logged in to the admin console)

ii) `anything@[MY_PROJECT_ID].appspotmail.com`,  `anything@[MY_PROJECT_NUMBER].appspotmail.com` which is an email that is directly tied to the project (like a service email address)

iii) Any email that you have listed under the `Email API Authorized Senders`.

Bullet 3 no longer works because Google App Engine is [discouraging](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/sending-messages) sending emails via the Mail bundled service. Instead they encourage using one of the commercial providers like Sendgrid, Mailjet, Mailgun

The only method that works for sure is bullet 1. I don't know about bullet 2 but 3 no longer works